# How to display SwiftUI Alert on top of all other Views and Sheets (MacOS)

Tags: swiftui, popup, alert, global

I am trying to display an `Alert` globally on top of all other views and sheets or alerts, that are open at that moment, so I can show a globally relevant error that can occur at all times while the program is running. Is this possible? My program is for the Mac, so a UIKit workaround does not work... Thanks in advance :)

You can apply the following modifier on any view and it will show the error on top of this view and other sheets and alerts, that are created in this view, but not on top of those sheets, that are created in subviews.

```
MyView()
    .modifier(AlertPresenter())

struct AlertPresenter: ViewModifier {
    @StateObject var alertViewModel: AlertViewModel = AlertViewModel()

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .alert(alertViewModel.errorTitle,
                   isPresented: $alertViewModel.showError,
                   actions: {
            Button("Ok") {
                alertViewModel.showError = false
            }
        }, message: {
            Text(alertViewModel.errorMessage)
        })
    }
}

class AlertViewModel: ObservableObject {    
    @Published var showError: Bool = false
    @Published var errorTitle: String = "An Error Occurred!"
    @Published var errorMessage: String = unknownString
    
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(errorOccurred), name: errorOccurredNotificationName, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func errorOccurred(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let error = notification.object as? Error else { return }
        errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
        showError = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Some observations: every time you use `.modifier(AlertPresenter())` it creates a new `AlertViewModel()`. You could try using `zIndex(...)` to put the alert
 on top of other views.

Comment: Thanks, I have now tried `zIndex(...)` out, but it doesn't work in this case. I have solved my concrete issue in a different not so elegant way now, but any ideas how I can do this properly are still very welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using modifier. Maybe you can do something like:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func errorAlert(error: Binding<Error?>, buttonTitle: LocalizedStringKey = "xloc.generic.ok", action: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
        let localizedAlertError = LocalizedAlertError(error: error.wrappedValue)
        alert(isPresented: .constant(localizedAlertError != nil), error: localizedAlertError) { _ in
            Button(buttonTitle) {
                action?()
                error.wrappedValue = nil
            }
        } message: { error in
            Text(error.failureReason ?? error.recoverySuggestion ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

You'll be able to show the error alert just like calling .alert(). Is this something you're trying to do?